# How to declare a static variable in Javascript?

Tags: google-apps-script, global-variables

How to declare a variable that its value can be changed globally by functions?

```
var a = 0;
var b = 0;

function c() {a = 5};
function d() {b = 6};

function e() {console.log(a+b)};

c();
d();
e();  // I expect here: 11
```

Comment: `e()` does log  `11`...

Comment: on console is 11, what's the problem?

Comment: a and b are global variables in this case, result will be 11

Comment: You're already doing it...I think it should be working

Comment: As far as I understand, he is trying to create `static` variables as his question title says which are possible as **function properties** (as he says `globally by functions`), I answered that question but probably it might not be what he is looking for since people here were fast enough to down vote within few seconds.

Comment: @Sarfraz You should consider reposting your answer, but with a bit of an explanation and not just some code.

Comment: @Niko: I was editing the answer, in the mean time, i got 5 down votes which made me rather delete it than edit it further, fast sunday today :)

Comment: Thank you Esailija. I use google AppScript and it doesn't work in that way.

Comment: @user1405507 You need to improve the question, e.g. add more details and clarify what the situation and the desired outcome is. Otherwise, this won't get reopened.

Comment: Thank you Niko. Unfortunately that's the most precise one that I can issue.

Comment: I think he meant the kind of `static` variables you use e.g. in C on the file level: Global (but only accessible within that .c file)

Answer (score 1):

Is that what you want? You can find lots of example when you search it.

```
  function count() {
        alert(count.num);
        count.num++;
    }

    // initialize count number
    count.num = 0;

    foo(); // alert 0
    foo(); // alert 1
```

Comment: Thank you Sarfraz, but not. Here we have a function which acts automatically when it is called. I need a GLOBAL STATIC variable which value's can be modified by function in a way that this change must be a global one. I mean every other function should "see" the modified value.

Comment: Sorry for everyone. This was my first post here and I made a mistake as per didn't mentioned or labeled that I tent to use Google AppScript. Regarding this fact the answer is here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_cache